# How do I generate random objects from my class Job which has an int and a string

Tags: java

```
class Job implements Comparable {

    int p;
    String name;

    public Job(String name, int p) {
        this.p = p;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Execute job:" + name + " - job p=" + p);
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Job x = (Job) o;
        if (p > x.p) {
            return 1;
        } else if (p == x.p)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Job j1 = new Job("Writer A",3);
        Job j2 = new Job("Writer B",2);
        Job j3 = new Job("Writer C",1);

        PriorityQueue que = new PriorityQueue();
        que.offer(j1);
        que.offer(j2);
        que.offer(j3);

        while(que.size()!=0){
            Job j = (Job)que.poll();
            j.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I generate 10 random objects from my "Job" class with the fields `name` and `p` and add them to my queue until the size is 20?  Adding them should be easy but how can I do that?

Comment: Adding them should be easy but how do I generate them

Comment: Depends how you want to generate the Job name.

Comment: Please see [ask]. What is it _exactly_ what you want to do? It is unclear what you mean by "generate 10 random objects". And how could you add only 10 to the queue until there are 20? Be as specific and clear as you can about what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 1):

Just extend your main method with a loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Job j1 = new Job("Writer A",3);
    Job j2 = new Job("Writer B",2);
    Job j3 = new Job("Writer C",1);

    PriorityQueue que = new PriorityQueue();
    que.offer(j1);
    que.offer(j2);
    que.offer(j3);

    // here you go with a loop
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        Job job = new Job('Writer ' + i , i);
        que.offer(job);
    }

    while(que.size()!=0){
        Job j = (Job)que.poll();
        j.execute();
    }
}
```